# Python function to replace letters

Tags: python, replace, punctuation

I need to remove the punctuation, I'm putting the question below with the code I have so far below that. I'm not sure what's not working and what I'm lacking - I'm trying to keep it as basic/simple as possible and only use the beginner stuff I've learned thus far. It says to use replace() so that's what I tried to do. Thanks!

**Define a function called strip_punctuation which takes one parameter, a string which represents a word, and removes characters considered punctuation from everywhere in the word. (Hint: remember the .replace() method for strings.)**

```
def strip_punctuation(punctuations):
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
for item in punctuations:
    if item in punctuation_chars:
        punctuations.replace(item, "")           
return punctuations
```

Comment: What does `punctuations` consist of? A list of strings?

Comment: Oh yeah - punctuations is supposed to be a string. Just a single string. I should have named it differently.

Comment: what part of it is not working? what's the main question? (also remember to indent your code)

Answer (score 3):

Python strings are immutable. `str.replace` doesn't modify the string, it returns a *new* string. So you want

```
punctuations = punctuations.replace(item, "")
```

Note that it's not necessary to check if `item` is in `punctuations` beforehand, `replace` just does nothing if the search string is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
def strip_punctuation(x):
    punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
    for ch in punctuation_chars:
        x=x.replace(ch,"")
    return x
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

(this function read a string and check it , is this string has punctuation marks as exist in the list (punctuation_chars) then it will replace the marks with empty string , so after function complete its mission it will return a string without punctuation_chars)

```py
punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']

def strip_punctuation (word):

    new_word = ""
    for w in word:
        if w in punctuation_chars :
            y= w.replace(w,"")
            new_word = new_word+y
        else:
            new_word = new_word+w

    return new_word
```

Comment: hi, if you provide code as answer, would be nice also to explain how it works and why it solves the problem in the question

Comment: hi ,  in general this function read a string and check it , is this string has punctuation marks as exist in the list (punctuation_chars) then it will replace the marks with empty string , so after function complete its mission it will return a string without punctuation_chars .
is that what you asked about ??

Comment: hi, I was suggesting to edit your answer and add the explanation you just gave me in the comment.

Comment: ia new here :) , i have tried many time but they refused , could you tell me how to put it please

Comment: to be honest not sure you can edit your answers at the beginning

Comment: thank you , i just wanted to help him , his question in online course ,i tried this code to solve the same problem and it worked with me

Comment: finally i did it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def strip_punctuation(x):
    punctuation_chars = ["'", '"', ",", ".", "!", ":", ";", '#', '@']
    for char in x:
        if char in punctuation_chars:
            x=x.replace(char, ' ')
            x=x.replace(' ','')
    return x

print(strip_punctuation('he.llo,'))
```

Try this, I make sure to eliminate the punctuations inside the string

Answer (score 0):

i think all diferent ... but don't use replace:

```
def strip_punctuation(x):
    palabra = ""
    for chr in x:
        if chr not in punctuation_chars:
            palabra += chr 
    return palabra
```

is more consistent. and small.